# Python advice: Portability of introspective function call

Tags: code-golf, tips, python

In Python, you can use the `dir` function on any object to get a list of the names of its instance functions:

```
>>> dir('abc')
['__add__', '__class__', '__contains__', '__delattr__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__getnewargs__', '__getslice__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__le__', '__len__', '__lt__', '__mod__', '__mul__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__rmod__', '__rmul__', '__setattr__','__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '_formatter_field_name_split', '_formatter_parser', 'capitalize', 'center', 'count', 'decode', 'encode', 'endswith', 'expandtabs', 'find', 'format', 'index', 'isalnum', 'isalpha', 'isdigit', 'islower', 'isspace', 'istitle', 'isupper', 'join', 'ljust', 'lower', 'lstrip', 'partition', 'replace', 'rfind', 'rindex', 'rjust', 'rpartition', 'rsplit', 'rstrip', 'split', 'splitlines', 'startswith', 'strip', 'swapcase', 'title', 'translate', 'upper', 'zfill']
```

I'm wondering if this could be a useful golfing technique in a program than calls several lengthily named functions. In such a case, I could create a function selection function `F`:

```
F=lambda o,i:eval('o.'+dir(o)[i])
```

Now suppose I have a string `s` and I want store the result of capitalizing its first letter in the variable `c`. Then instead of `c=s.capitalize(),` I could note that `capitalize` is at position 33 in the above list and do the following:

```
s='abc'
c=G(s,33)()
```

which assigns `'Abc'` to `c`.

My question is whether this is likely to work most of the time. In particular,

- Can I always count on the list being lexicographically sorted by ASCII values?
- Are there many changes to list of available between minor versions?
- Do differences exist between implementations?

Also, has anyone used this before on PPCG?

Comment: I've seen similar things done with JavaScript and C#.

Comment: You can also do this with builtins: `dir(__builtins__)`. And here's an alternative function: `F=lambda o,i:getattr(o,dir(o)[i])`.

Comment: Also note that depending on which functions you plan on using, you could add the `()` to the end of `F` like so: `F=lambda o,i:eval('o.'+dir(o)[i])()` Then `c=F('abc',33)` will assign 'Abc' to `c`.

Answer (score 6):

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#dir):

> The resulting list is sorted alphabetically

As for the differences, I think you will have to check (and specifying in your answer is probably a good idea). There are clear differences between python 2 and 3, for example, `__nonzero__` was renamed to `__bool__`.

I have never heard of any differences between implementations, but I can't find any references on this.

I don't think this has been used before in part because it will rarely save you any characters over doing something like:

```
F=str.capitalize
s='abc'
c=F(s)
```

You would need to use several different functions from `dir()` in order for this to be worth it.